# Convert Ruby array of hashes into one hash

Tags: ruby, arrays, hashmap

I have the following array:

```
array = [{"a" => 2}, {"b" => 3}, {"a" => nil}, {"c" => 2}, {"b" => nil}]
```

I want to convert it into 1 big hash but keep all of the values, so I want it to look like the following:

```
{"a" => [2, nil], "b" => [3, nil], "c" => [2]}
```

I can get close doing `array.inject({}) {|s, h| s.merge(h)}}`, but it overwrites the values.

Comment: wouldn't it make more sense to have `"c"=> [2]` in the hash?

Comment: yea that works as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array = [{"a" => 2}, {"b" => 3}, {"a" => nil}, {"c" => 2}, {"b" => nil}]
a = array.each_with_object(Hash.new([])) do |h1,h|
  h1.each{|k,v| h[k] = h[k] + [v]}
end
a # => {"a"=>[2, nil], "b"=>[3, nil], "c"=>[2]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array = [{"a" => 2}, {"b" => 3}, {"a" => nil}, {"c" => 2}, {"b" => nil}]
res = {}

array.each do |hash|
  hash.each do |k, v|
    res[k] ||= []
    res[k] << v
  end
end
```

Comment: You can get rid of the `res[k] ||= []` line if you change `res = {}` to `res = Hash.new []`

Comment: thanks @naomik but I like it this way. There are some strange stuff going on when you use Hash with default values